# Finding and replacing

Tags: api, haskell

There are times that we want to find an element in a list with a function `a -> Bool` and replace it using a function `a -> a`, this may result in a new list:

```
findr :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
findr _ _ [] = Nothing
findr p f (x:xs) 
  | p x = Just (f x : xs)
  | otherwise = case findr p f xs of Just xs -> Just (x:xs)
                                     _ -> Nothing
```

Is there any function in the main modules which is similar to this?

Comment: You can answer this question yourself by running a search with the desired type signature on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de).

Comment: @Jubobs - Yes... Actually I tried it without success before, this was the reason I posted this question looking for a similar implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: @gallais points out below that you end up only changing the first instance; I thought you were changing every instance.

This is done with `break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` which gives you the longest prefix which does not satisfy the predicate, followed by the rest of the list.

```
findr p f list = case break p list of
             (xs, y : ys) -> Just (xs ++ f y : ys)
             (_, [])      -> Nothing
```

Comment: In OP's question, `f` is not mapped to all `x` such that `p x` but only the *first one*.

Comment: @gallais: originally I thought you were wrong but I can see now that you're totally right! Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, don't you think this function should be in `Data.List`?

Answer (score 1):

This function is, of course, `map`, as long as you can combine your predicate function and replacement function the right way.

```
findr check_f replace_f xs = map (replace_if_needed check_f replace_f) xs

replace_if_needed :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
replace_if_needed check_f replace_f = \x -> if check_f x then replace_f x else x
```

Now you can do things like `findr isAplha toUpper "a123-bc"`.